# Azure Android CloudAppendBlob leads to Error 409 (Conflict) when trying to view the data

Tags: java, android, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm currently testing the MS Azure Storage API for Android I found here: [github: azure-storage-android](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-android).

I tried the sample code and it is working fine. Assume the setup of the `CloudStorageAccount`, the `CloudBlobClient` and the `CloudBlobContainer` is already done as showcased by the sample (also found in the same git repo)

Following code works fine:

```
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.getBlockBlobReference("blockblob");
blockBlob.uploadText("foobar");
```

When I run this code and look at the Blob Container using e.g. the `Azure Storage Explorer` everything is fine. Here is the result:
[image: azure success]

Now the error-case:

Switching from

`container.getBlockBlobReference("...")`

to

`container.getAppendBlobReference("...")`

and working with `CloudAppendBlob` instead of `CloudBlockBlob` as seen in this snippet:

```
CloudAppendBlob appendBlob = container.getAppendBlobReference("appendblob");
appendBlob.createOrReplace();
appendBlob.appendText("foobar");
```

leaves me with following error every time I try to read container data:

> Error retrieving blob list: 409 Conflict

[image: azure error]

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?
I tried using `Leases` but it didn't change the result.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Emily mentioned in her comments, the issue is with Azure Storage Explorer tool. Append Blobs are supported in the latest version of Storage API and unfortunately the tool is not updated to make use of the latest version.

You can make use of other tools that support the latest version of Storage API and thus Append Blobs. A few of them I can recommend are: [`Cloud Portam`](http://www.cloudportam.com) [Full Disclosure: I am building this tool], [`Cerebrata Azure Explorer`](http://www.cerebrata.com/products/azure-explorer/introduction), [`Cerebrata Azure Management Studio`](http://www.cerebrata.com/products/azure-management-studio/introduction) and [`ClumsyLeaf CloudXplorer`](http://clumsyleaf.com/products/cloudxplorer).

Comment: Thank you very much! As for answering my question, I tested `Cloud Portam` and it works! `ClumsyLeaf CloudXplorer` also works! I was hoping the problem lies in the software. I also used the `Azure Web Storage Explorer` but it produced a similar error. `Cerebrata Azure Explorer` didn't work so I didn't even bother trying `Cerebrata Azure Management Studio`.